# Convert: timeinfo = localtime(&now) to 24Hr, then extract tm_hour, C/C++. Syntax assistance

Tags: esp8266, time.h

I'm using time.h with tm_hour to get the hour of the day, but the time is in 12 Hr format by default.
I need 24 Hour format (00-23 Hrs) for simple event time code, like:

```
time_t now;
  struct tm * timeinfo;
  time(&now);
  timeinfo = localtime(&now);
  Serial.println("24 Hr Time is: %H:%M:%S\n", timeinfo->tm_hour, timeinfo->tm_min, timeinfo->tm_sec);  //test
  Serial.println(timeinfo->tm_hour);
    if ((timeinfo->tm_hour)>= 22) // 10PM Event
        //Do something here
```

Any syntax assistance appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure? `tm_hour` is supposed to contain a value between 0 and 23. There is no other field in `tm` to indicate AM/PM. If `tm_hour` wraps around at 12, it would be a bug in the library. Have you set a time zone?

Comment: No, I believe tm_hour wraps at 12 hour.  Time zone is set to 7 using: configTime(timezone * 3600, dst * 0, "pool.ntp.org", "time.nist.gov");

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, time zone offset 7 is for the India, Kazakhstan, Russia region. Have you tried -7? I think the sign of the timezone offset is a bit confusing and there was a bug in that code.